# The magic square function

Tags: matrix

There are some matrices such that the sum of columns, the sum of rows, and the sum of diagonals are the same value. Here is an example:

```
 8     1     6
 3     5     7
 4     9     2
```

The sum of rows is 15, and so is sum of columns and the sum of diagonals.

In MATLAB, refer to Cleve Moler's book ["Experiments with MATLAB"](https://www.mathworks.com/content/dam/mathworks/mathworks-dot-com/moler/exm/chapters/magic.pdf). I can generate this kind of matrix using the `magic`function, with an argument specifying the size of the matrix:

4-by-4:

```
>> magic(4)
ans =
    16     2     3    13
     5    11    10     8
     9     7     6    12
     4    14    15     1
```

5-by-5:

```
>> magic(5)
ans =
    17    24     1     8    15
    23     5     7    14    16
     4     6    13    20    22
    10    12    19    21     3
    11    18    25     2     9
```

Is there a similar function in *Mathematica*? Or, maybe there's some way to build this kind of matrix?

Comment: @Amzoti No, I haven't. Thank you for pointing it out, great source!

Comment: @Amzoti Unfortunately that Notebook relies on a package that is no longer available as far as I can tell.  Here is an image of the download page in the Internet Archive, but the MagicSquares link does not work:  http://web.archive.org/web/20110215143835/http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/4775

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Translated Cleve Moler's magic() function from Matlab code to Mathematica.

```
Grid[Partition[MatrixForm@magic[#] & /@ {3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}, 4], 
    Frame -> All, FrameStyle -> LightGray]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

code:

```
magic[n_Integer /; (n > 0 && n != 2)] := Module[{m, j, k, p, i},
   (*Translation of Cleve Moler's magic magic() function to Mathematica*)
   Which[
    Mod[n, 2] == 1, m = oddOrderMagicSquare[n],
    Mod[n, 4] == 0,
    j = Floor  @ Abs [ Mod[Range[n], 4]/2];
    k = Outer[Equal, j, j] /. {True -> 1, False -> 0};
    m = Outer[Plus, Range[1, n*n, n], Range[0, n - 1]];
    p = Position[k, 1];
    (m[[Sequence @@ #]] = n*n + 1 - m[[Sequence @@ #]]) & /@ p,
    True,
    p = n/2;
    m = oddOrderMagicSquare[p];
    m = ArrayFlatten@{{m, m + 2*p^2}, {m + 3*p^2, m + p^2}};
    If[n != 2,
     i = Range[p];
     k = (n - 2)/4;
     j = {Range[k], Range[n - k + 2, n]};
     j = Flatten@DeleteCases[j, {}];
     m[[Join[i, i + p], j]] = m[[Join[i + p, i], j]]
     ]
    ];
   m
   ];
oddOrderMagicSquare[n_] := Module[{p},
   p = Range[n];
   Transpose[n*Mod[Map[p + # &, p - (n + 3)/2], n] + 
      Mod[Map[p + # &, 2*p - 2], n] + 1]
   ];
```

Comment: Put some conditions on n == 2. No magic square of order 2.

Comment: @Hans thanks. I changed the signature to check for n!=2

Comment: Thank you very much. The output is also beautiful.

Answer (score 22):

@Nasser's answer is nice, but slowly when `Mod[n,4]==0`. Here is a faster code, efficiency is close to Matlab :

```
ClearAll[magic]
magic[n_?OddQ] := oddOrderMagicSquare[n];

magic[n_ /; n~Mod~4 == 0] :=
  Module[{J, K1, M},
    J = Floor[(Range[n]~Mod~4)/2.0];
    K1 = Abs@Outer[Plus, J, -J]~BitXor~1;
    M = Outer[Plus, Range[1, n^2, n], Range[0, n - 1]];
    M + K1 (n*n + 1 - 2 M)
    ] // Experimental`CompileEvaluate;

magic[n_?EvenQ] :=
  Module[{p, M, i, j, k},
   p = n/2;(*p is odd*)
   M = oddOrderMagicSquare[p];
   M = ArrayFlatten@{{M, M + 2 p^2}, {M + 3 p^2, M + p^2}};
   If[n == 2, Return[M]];
   i = Transpose@{Range@p};
   k = (n - 2)/4;
   j = Range[k]~Join~Range[n - k + 2, n];
   M[[Flatten@{i, i + p}, j]] = M[[Flatten@{i + p, i}, j]];
   i = k + 1;
   j = {1, i};
   M[[Flatten@{i, i + p}, j]] = M[[Flatten@{i + p, i}, j]];
   M
   ];

oddOrderMagicSquare[n_?OddQ] :=
  Module[{p},
   p = Range[n];
   Outer[Plus, p, p - (n + 3)/2]~Mod~n*n + 
    Outer[Plus, p, 2 p - 2]~Mod~n + 1
   ];

magic[3000]; // AbsoluteTiming
magic[3001]; // AbsoluteTiming
magic[3002]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

Comment: good you tried to speed it up. I translated Matlab code line by line, did not try to make any changes since I wanted first to get it working correctly. But speeding it up is interesting exercise on its own.

Comment: Thank you very much. It's really hard for me as a beginner to decide whose answer is the right one. Since @Nasser is the original answer, I marked his right answer. I'm sorry, I can only vote up for yours.

Comment: @Nick Don't worry about that.

Comment: @chyaong, Could you give some explanation(or your algorithm ) to help me to understand your high efficiency implementation when $n$ is doubly-even? thanks a lot:)