# Speed up the auxiliary function magicSquare when $n$ is doubly-even

Tags: matrix, performance-tuning

Today, I saw a question about magic square (please see [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/73131/the-magic-square-function/82698)). When $n$ is doubly-even, namely for `Mod[n,4]==0`

```
magicSquare[n_] /; Mod[n, 4] == 0 :=
 Module[{mat1, mat2, square, bools},
  mat1 = Table[Range[n], {i, n}];
  mat2 = Transpose@mat1;
  square = Partition[Range[1, n^2], n];
  bools =
   MapThread[
    Equal,
    {Floor[Mod[mat2, 4]/2], Floor[Mod[mat1, 4]/2]}, 2];
  Apply[
   If[#2, n^2 + 1 - #1, #1] &,
  MapThread[List, {square, bools}, 2], {2}]
 ]
```

Algorithm for doubly-even

> [image]
>   [image]

For example, let $n=4$

> [image]
>   [image]

**Test**

```
magicSquare[3000]; // AbsoluteTiming (* n is doubly-even*)
```

> ```
> {40.0029297, Null}
> ```

Obviously, it is rather time-consuming. In addition, I write a  function `magicQ[A]` that checks if `A` is a magic square

```
magicQ[mat_?MatrixQ] /; Equal @@ Dimensions@mat :=
 Module[
  {n = Length@mat, row, col, diagonal},
  row = Total[mat, {2}];
  col = Total[mat, {1}];
  diagonal = {Tr@mat, Tr@Transpose@mat};
  Union[row, col, diagonal] == {(n^3 + n)/2}
 ]

magicSquare[3000] // magicQ // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {6.8847656, True}
> ```

---

**Question**

- How to speed up this `magicSquare` function?
- Search for more efficient solution for `magicQ`.

Comment: Where's the definition of `magic1`? By the way `Tr@Transpose@mat` should be something like `Tr@Reverse@mat`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The main reason for the slowness of the `magicSquare` is that your failed to insist on vecterization. (you're already aware of its importance, right? ) Making use of the internal functions owning `Listable` attribute and treating lists as a whole as much as possible, it's not hard to come to the following:

```
magicSquare2[n_] /; Mod[n, 4] == 0 := 
 Module[{mat, square, bools}, mat = ConstantArray[Range[1., n], n];
  square = Partition[Range[n^2], n];
  bools = UnitStep@-Abs[# - #\[Transpose] &@Floor[Mod[mat, 4]/2]];
  n^2 + 1 - #1 &@square bools + (1 - bools) square]

ans1 = magicSquare[3000]; // AbsoluteTiming
ans2 = magicSquare2[3000]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {23.320632, Null}
> {0.796866, Null}
> ```

Two other tiny changes I've made in `magicSquare2` are

1. Use `ConstantArray` instead of `Table`.
2. Change `Range[n]` to `Range[1., n]` so `mat` will become a `MachinePrecision`
   matrix and the calculation of `Mod[mat, 4]/2` will be sped up.

If you have a C compiler installed:

```
magicSquare3[n_] /; Mod[n, 4] == 0 := cfmagicSquare3[n]
cfmagicSquare3 = 
  With[{g = Compile`GetElement}, 
   Compile[{{n, _Integer}}, 
    Module[{mat1, mat2, square}, 
     mat1 = Floor[Mod[Table[Range[1., n], {n}], 4]/2];
     mat2 = mat1\[Transpose];
     square = Partition[Range[n^2], n];
     Table[
      If[g[mat1, i, j] == g[mat2, i, j], n^2 + 1 - g[square, i, j], 
       g[square, i, j]], {i, n}, {j, n}]], CompilationTarget -> C, 
    RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"]];

ans3 = magicSquare3[3000]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {0.281241, Null}
> ```

Tricks used in the above piece of code are almost all inherited from [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/61597/1871). The only thing I can add here is, `mat2 = mat1\[Transpose];` is necessary for speed, I'm not sure about the reason, maybe it's because that if one eliminate this line and use `g[mat1, i, j] == g[mat1, j, i]` in the last `Table`, `g[mat1, j, i]` will cause more frequent access for the higher dimension of `mat1`, which is slower than that for lower dimension. (You remember the truth that for `n = 10^3; test = RandomReal[1, {n, n}];`, `test[[All, 1]]` is slower than `test[[1]]`? )

As to the `magicQ`, despite of the mistake mentioned in the comment above, I think it's already quite efficient and simple. Of course one can create a faster one, still, by compiling to C:

```
With[{g = Compile`GetElement}, Block[{check1, check2},
   check1[mat_, n_, tot_]:= Do[If[Sum[g[mat, i, j], {j, n}] != tot, Throw@False], {i, n}];
   check2[mat_, n_, tot_]:= If[Sum[g[mat, j, j], {j, n}] != tot, Throw@False];
   cfmagicQ2 = 
    Hold@Compile[{{mat, _Integer, 2}}, 
        Module[{n = Length@mat, mat2 = mat\[Transpose], mat3 = Reverse[mat], tot}, 
         tot = (n^3 + n)/2; 
         Catch[check1[mat, n, tot]; check1[mat2, n, tot]; check2[mat, n, tot]; 
          check2[mat3, n, tot]; True]], CompilationTarget -> C, 
        RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"] //. Flatten[DownValues /@ {check1, check2}] // 
     ReleaseHold];
  magicQ2[mat_?MatrixQ] /; Equal @@ Dimensions@mat := cfmagicQ2[mat]];

test = ans3; test[[100, 100]] = 0;
ans3 // magicQ // AbsoluteTiming
test // magicQ // AbsoluteTiming
ans3 // magicQ2 // AbsoluteTiming
test // magicQ2 // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {0.156215, True}
> {0.156223, False}
> {0.062461, True}
> {0.046865, False}
> ```

Tricks for speeding up the compiled code is the same as those used in `magicSquare3`. `Throw` and `Catch` will make the calculation stop once the matrix is detected as "non-magic" thus judgement for non-magic square is sped up. Notice that I've used a code auto-generation technique for simplicity, which is inherited from [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/47489/1871).

Comment: Thanks a lot. And I need some time to understand your code:)

Comment: @ShutaoTang I've added some brief explanation, hope it helps.

Comment: `UnitStep@-Abs[# - #\[Transpose] &@Floor[Mod[mat, 4]/2]]` is much efficient than  `MapThread[
  Equal, {Floor[Mod[mat2, 4]/2], Floor[Mod[mat1, 4]/2]}, 2`. For instance,  `mat1 = RandomReal[{1, 10}, {3000, 3000}];MapThread[
   Equal, {Floor[Mod[mat1\[Transpose], 4]/2], Floor[Mod[mat1, 4]/2]}, 
   2]; // AbsoluteTiming  UnitStep@-Abs[# - #\[Transpose] &@
      Floor[Mod[mat1, 4]/2]]; // AbsoluteTiming`   gives the following result `{5.6494141, Null},{0.7744141, Null}`

Comment: BTW, How can I find the documentation about `Compile`GetElement`?

Comment: @ShutaoTang It's undocumented, but mentioned in a few posts here, for example [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/824/1871). You can have a search for more…Well, I admit I found no detailed explanation for so long. Maybe you can consider asking a separate question for this issue?

Comment: Ok, thanks.@xzczd I learned a lot from you:)