Remove dupes from output of a magicSquare
I have this code to generate a number of 3x3 magic squares, using a range of 900k random samples.
It works fine, but the issue is, it generates repeats as shown in the outputs.
I tried sandwiching Thread OR RandomSample with  DeleteDuplicates, but neither of the 2 changes removes dupes.
Full code included as per request in the comment below:
mat = {{a, b, c}, {d, e, f}, {g, h, i}};
Total /@ mat;
Total /@ Transpose[mat];
Tr[mat];
Tr[Reverse /@ mat];
eq = {Total /@ mat, Total /@ Transpose[mat], Tr[mat],Tr[Reverse /@ mat]} // Flatten;

Do[ra = RandomSample[Range[9], 9];
 If[ContainsExactly[eq /. Thread[Flatten@mat -> ra], {15}], 
  Print[MatrixForm@Partition[ra, 3]]], 900000]

Any help, or improvements would be appreciated. I like to know how many unique sets there are. I suppose rotations of 90 degrees are still considered unique, although it would be nice to rule them out in a different output also.
P.S. In addition, didn't use ResourceFunction["MagicSquare"] as it generates the same one only! Assume there is no way to make it generate others.
[[Updated]]
DeleteDuplicates Tries:
Do[ra = RandomSample[Range[9], 9];
 If[ContainsExactly[
   eq /. DeleteDuplicates[Thread[Flatten@mat -> ra], {15}]], 
  Print[MatrixForm@Partition[ra, 3]]], 900000]

Or:
Do[ra = DeleteDuplicates[RandomSample[Range[9], 9]];
 If[ContainsExactly[eq /. Thread[Flatten@mat -> ra], {15}], 
  Print[MatrixForm@Partition[ra, 3]]], 900000]



Please provide all code required to run your code without errors.

Maybe something like Partition[#, 3] & /@ Permutations[Range[9]]; magicSquares =    DeleteDuplicates@    Select[%,      Total@# == {15, 15, 15} && Total[#, {2}] == {15, 15, 15} &]; is a start? I think this generates all magic squares of size 3 by 3 by generating all possible 3 by 3 matrices with distinct entries from 1 to 9 and prunes them so that the sums of the rows and columns are all 15. Then, if you want, you can start pruning them according to rotational symmetry, etc.

Thanks @march ...This is very good and elegant!  Is there a way I can put the outputs in matrix similar to mine? I tried but it gives 3 matrices of 3x1 side by side.   Also I assume 4x4 will be similar , hope it will not take forever.

9! is 362880, and so it only has to check that many matrices. 16! is 20922789888000. I do not recommend generating all magic squares of size 4 by 4 in this way.

You can always do MatrixForm /@ magicSquares, but I only recommend doing this if you are planning on jsut displaying the matrices.  You won't be able to do any operations on the matrices if you wrap them in MatrixForm.

Do you still want to rule out rotations? and perhaps reflections?

"I tried sandwiching Thread OR RandomSample with DeleteDuplicates, but neither of the 2 changes removes dupes." So, how do you use DeleteDuplicates? Please show us the specific code so we can tell you what's wrong. The question will be reopened once it meets the standard of the site.

Hi @xzczd  updated with the 2 tries. This is a valid question, not sure why you insist on closing it. Either way I already got my answer

@Steve237 I think the way you posed your question left uncertainty about what you had tried and what resulted. You used the same graphic in the updated question. Is it really always same output for the other trials.  IMHO this motivated closing question pending clarification.

Yes, our community members are always kind, but since I believe the question needs clarification, I voted to close. This sounds harsh, but to be straightforward: I don't want the birth of a second user:68574. Then, as to the updated code, I'd argue it's a logic problem rather than a Mathematica problem: what you want is to remove duplicates from the output, but you're using DeleteDuplicates on intermediate steps! Just use Table instead of Do, and use DeleteDuplicates outside of Table, and remove Print.

So if you are proposing a solution in this comment, you understood the issue and are providing an answer. Hence logically it was a valid question. Makes little sense to close it.  This is not just MMA issue, it is logic as well, in fact that's the gist of it.

An understandable question isn't necessarily a on-topic question. In my view, now the question has fallen into "This question arises due to a simple mistake" category. Of course, there always exists a grey zone, and I won't be against the decision if other community members vote to reopen this question.

This is not a way to remove duplicates but a way (for the 3 x 3 case) to generate the magic squares without searching through random instances.
s = Select[Subsets[Range[9], {3}], Total@# == 15 &];
ss = Join @@ (Permutations /@ 
     Join @@ (Tuples[Permutations /@ #] & /@ Subsets[s, {3}]));
res = With[{i = {1, 1, 1}, y = {15, 15, 15}},
   Select[
    ss, # . i == y && Transpose[#] . i == y && Tr[#] == 15 && 
      Tr[Reverse /@ #] == 15 && Length[Union[Flatten[#]]] == 9 &]];
Grid[Partition[MatrixForm /@ res, 4], Frame -> All, FrameStyle -> Red]



Thank you for accept but wait for other answers. I did not answer your specific question but (for this 3x3 case), thought I’d offer an alternative.

Nice solution @ubpdqn   makes me think there is only ONE unique solution, even your 8 sets all have repeat rotations. rotate R1C1 90 degrees left you get R2C2     then rotate R1C2 90 degees right you get R2C1  etc...   in other words, for example: 6,1,8 must always be together, either in Row or Col.  Yes they can be permuted in diff ways. Same with others, for example, 4,5,6 is always in the diagonal positions! etc

Sure will wait, if a better one comes along, will switch over! With your permission in advance!

@Steve237 I suspect there will be better answers and choose the one that suits your needs. Good luck.

There will bo no further answers if the question remains closed

@rhermans xzczd reasonably asked OP to clarify question. I did not close question but understood reason it was closed. My answer was just meant to start. Apparently OP got what they wanted.

Side note: guys are interested in magic square problem may want to check https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/73131/1871 and https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/82702/1871 .

@xzczd very useful links
